# Get a build id using a Build number

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

currently I am working in a project to convert all release pipeline from classic to yaml.

so in downloadpipelineartifact we need to give a build id

so here instead of giving the build ID directly in the code each time I will give the ID using parameters

```
             parameters:
             - name: fbuildid
               displayName: Build ID
               type: string
               default: ''
            
              - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
                inputs:
                  buildType: 'specific'
                  project: 'affda316-830a-45e7-befe-b85b497e6b1b'
                  definition: '10'
                  buildVersionToDownload: 'specific'
                  pipelineId:  '${{ parameters.fbuildid }}' 
                  targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
```

but if I directly mention the build no its not accepting it asks for Build id which I later realized

so how can I get build ID using a build no at run time using any code in YAML

Comment: Could you provide more information and tell:
1. what it means that "its not accepting it asks for Build id"? Could you confirm that the pipeline with the definition: '10' publish the Pipeline Artifacts and not the Build Artifacts and it is not the same pipeline from which you are running this task?